# What's The Cheapest Way to Level inscription In World Of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Inscription is the newest profession in World of Warcraft. What's the cheapest way to level inscription in world of warcraft?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the cheapest way to level inscription in world of warcraft?

Regardless of which guide you follow, the cheapest way (when only looking at gold as a cost factor) is always going to be to take up Herbalism as well or have an alt with Herbalism.

Using your favourite Inscription levelling guide and [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com) for example you can find the best routes for specific herbs and farm away.

Some addons such as *Routes* and *Gatherer* also help improve the speed in which you farm your herbs.

That doesn't mean it is the fastest but that would be the cheapest way as it costs you no gold.

However, there is an argument whereby **time** also is a sort of cost. Due to that, a lot of people find it more cost effective to do other tasks which take less time that make the gold you need to buy the required herbs for levelling Inscription with spare change and time left at the end.

But that is another whole topic in it's own I think.

Comment: Time is not a sort of cost, it is a concrete cost. The only reason you should farm materials yourself is if they aren't available on the AH. If it would be cheaper for you to farm them than it would be to do whatever it is you do for money and buy them, then clearly they're a better money source than what you currently do for money.

Comment: @corsiKlauseHoHoHo: +1 I do agree that time is a concrete factor, at the time of writing this (no pun intended) I wanted to be careful in the phrasing as a lot of players in the community would not understand the time factor and sometimes even quite aggressively disregarded it as an argument. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't stepping on anyone's toes at the time :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.elsprofessions.com/inscription/leveling.html provides the best levelling guide for Inscription.